# SQL: Need to select rows where at least 3 columns are not equal to specific value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to select rows where at least three columns are not equal to "Unknown"

Example dataset:

```
id     condition_A      condition_B      condition_C     condition_D     Condition_E    
1      Unknown          Positive         Negative        Negative        Unknown
2      Unknown          Unknown          Negative        Negative        Unknown
3      Positive         Positive         Negative        Negative        Unknown
```

In this case I would want the query to return rows 1 and 3.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sample data is great, but also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Hint: `case` expressions.

Comment: You need to use `case when....` statements for every three combinations of columns to check 'Unknown' value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
select * from tablename
where 3 <=
  (condition_A <> 'Unknown')::int + 
  (condition_B <> 'Unknown')::int + 
  (condition_C <> 'Unknown')::int + 
  (condition_D <> 'Unknown')::int + 
  (condition_E <> 'Unknown')::int
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wsxAfJkW71upme5F8Q8JuH/0).
Results:

```
| id  | condition_a | condition_b | condition_c | condition_d | condition_e |
| --- | ----------- | ----------- | ----------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| 1   | Unknown     | Positive    | Negative    | Negative    | Unknown     |
| 3   | Positive    | Positive    | Negative    | Negative    | Unknown     |
```